# AWS Python: Return values from response

Tags: python, boto3

My aim is to have a lambda that parses the cloudformation stack drift resources and then prints out a list of all Security Groups that have been modified.

The following will return a list of ALL modified resources for a specific stack:

```
import boto3

cfn_client = boto3.client('cloudformation')

drifts = cfn_client.describe_stack_resource_drifts(
    StackName='my_stack>',
    StackResourceDriftStatusFilters=[
      'MODIFIED',
    ],
    MaxResults=100
)
```

Which returns a dict response with (I've only included the fields relevant to the question):

```
{
  'ResponseMetadata': {
    'RetryAttempts': 0,
    'HTTPStatusCode': 200,
    'RequestId': '12b1f618-722e-4b08-9534-123',
    'HTTPHeaders': {
      'content-type': 'text/xml',
      'content-length': '118369',
      'vary': 'accept-encoding',
      'date': 'Tue, 18 Aug 2020 11:11:38 GMT'
    }
  },
  u 'StackResourceDrifts': [{
    u 'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:12345678:stack/my_stack/12345,
    u 'ResourceType': 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup',
    u 'PhysicalResourceId': 'sg-987654321xyz',
    u 'StackResourceDriftStatus': 'MODIFIED',
    u 'LogicalResourceId': 'MySecGrp1'
  }, {
    u 'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:12345678:stack/my_stack/12345,
    u 'ResourceType': 'AWS::ElasticLoadBalancingV2::TargetGroup',
    u 'PhysicalResourceId': 'arn:aws:elasticloadbalancing:eu-west-1:12345678:targetgroup/my_resource_id',
    u 'StackResourceDriftStatus': 'MODIFIED',
    u 'LogicalResourceId': 'NyTargerGroup1'
  }, {
    u 'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:12345678:stack/my_stack/12345,
    u 'ResourceType': 'AWS::EC2::Instance',
    u 'PhysicalResourceId': 'i-123456789xyz',
    u 'StackResourceDriftStatus': 'MODIFIED',
    u 'LogicalResourceId': 'MyServer1'
  }, {
    u 'StackId': 'arn:aws:cloudformation:eu-west-1:12345678:stack/my_stack/12345,
    u 'ResourceType': 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup',
    u 'PhysicalResourceId': 'sg-123456789xyz',
    u 'StackResourceDriftStatus': 'MODIFIED',
    u 'LogicalResourceId': 'MySecGrp2'
  }]
}
```

I'm trying to print out the `PhysicalResourceId` and `LogicalResourceId` where `ResourceType` == `AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup`. There could be multiple of these in one response.

I've only gotten so far as being able to see how to return a specific value, but it's a far way off from what I need still: `print (drifts ['StackResourceDrifts'][0]['ResourceType'])`

I'm new to Python, so would appreciate help on how to achieve this.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Try this. Final will be list of dictionary.

```
final = []
for item in drifts['StackResourceDrifts']:
    if item['ResourceType'] == 'AWS::EC2::SecurityGroup':
        final.append({'PhysicalResourceId': item['PhysicalResourceId'],
              'LogicalResourceId': item['LogicalResourceId']
              })

print(final)
```